# What does era mean in NSDateComponents?

Tags: objective-c

Sorry if this seems to be a silly question, but Ive just come across this part of NSDateComponents, and was puzzled as to what it actually represents. My mind was wondering if Objective C actually has a list of era's built into it, like the Era of Diocletian or the Seleucid Era, but then I dismissed this thought as being silly.

So what era does the `NSDateComponent era` actually refer to? Is it just a matter of BC / AD, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in the Gregorian Calendar there are two eras, BC and AD.

[Apple Dev:  Historical Dates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtHist.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, the Apple docs do not explicitly explain the actual values, but for the Gregorian calendar, era 0 is BC, and era 1 is AD, as you would expect. I have yet to find an official list of era values.

Answer (score 6):

It's BC/AD for the Gregorian calendar, but there are other eras in other calendars (e.g., [Japanese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_era_name)).